# Page doesnt change / next

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

Why the page doesn't change, but also don't receive an error in console.

Can someone please help me in this case?

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("»").click()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your href is "#" is the page supposed to change? Probably the element is indeed clicked, but this doesn't trigger page change. If you click the link manually does the page change?
What happens if you try

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.last").click()
```

It would be useful if you can provide a link to publicly available page under test

Comment: yes, if i click manually is changing

Comment: an i have no other way to reach that location, I dont have a different link or something like this

Comment: my bad , i didnt had a sleep time before the command ... thank you